# Avoid TListView drawing/updating while mouse hovering/over

Tags: delphi

I have a `TListView` with some modifications.  It includes some icons (several, depending on the item) per row, as well as the possibility of a background for a row if certain conditions are met.

It seems to be rendering all right.  But a problem occurs when I move the mouse over the window, it seems like the rows are being re-rendered, this creates an unnecessary lag and more importantly, it seems to mess with the visualisation.  It should only re-draw if I do something (like select a row).

How do I force it to stop (seemingly refreshing rows upon mouse over)?  Currently I am using the `AdvancedCustomDrawItem` to draw.  It also takes like a second for the window to react to a selection of an item, that seems dull.

So basically, each row has `DrawText()` and drawing images onto the `Sender.Canvas`.  This is admittedly a slow progress, but it works for now, if it just didn't seemingly redraw the rows when I hover over them!  In fact, if I use the Aero theme, the rows become black when you hover over them.

Here is my event code on `AdvancedCustomDrawItem`:

```
procedure TfrmJobQueue.ListView1AdvancedCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; Stage: TCustomDrawStage;
  var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
const
  DT_ALIGN: array[TAlignment] of integer = (DT_LEFT, DT_RIGHT, DT_CENTER);
var
  r: TRect;
  SL: TStringList;
  TypeName: string;
  I: Integer;
  TypeState: integer;
  x1,x2: Integer;
  S: string;
begin
  if Stage = cdPostPaint then begin
    // Ways I tried to avoid it; but failed.
    if cdsHot in State then
      exit;
    if cdsNearHot in State then
      exit;
    if cdsOtherSideHot in State then
      exit;
    if cdsMarked in State then
      exit;
    if cdsIndeterminate in State then
      exit;
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
    if FRepLines.Items[Item.Index].IsAutoReport then begin
      Sender.Canvas.Font.Color  := clBlack;
      Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clSkyBlue;
    end else begin
      Sender.Canvas.Font.Color  := clBlack;
      Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
    end;
    if cdsSelected in State then begin
      Sender.Canvas.Font.Color  := clWhite;
      Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clNavy;
    end;
    R := Item.DisplayRect(drBounds);
    Sender.Canvas.FillRect(R);
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    if cdsFocused in State then
      DrawFocusRect(Sender.Canvas.Handle, R);
    x1 := 0;
    x2 := 0;
    for i := 0 to TListView(Sender).Columns.Count - 1 do
    begin
      inc(x2, Sender.Column[i].Width);
      r.Left := x1;
      r.Right := x2;
      if i = 0 then
    S := Item.Caption
      else
    S := Item.SubItems[i-1];
      if DT_ALIGN[Sender.Column[i].Alignment] = DT_LEFT then
    S := '  ' + S;
      DrawText(Sender.Canvas.Handle,
    S, length(S), r,
    DT_SINGLELINE or DT_ALIGN[Sender.Column[i].Alignment] or
      DT_VCENTER or DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
      x1 := x2;
    end;
    r := Item.DisplayRect(drIcon);
    SL := TStringList.Create;
    SL.CommaText := FRepLines.Value(Item.Index, 'TypeState');
    r.Left := Sender.Column[0].Width + Sender.Column[1].Width + Sender.Column[2].Width + Sender.Column[3].Width
      + Sender.Column[4].Width;
    for I := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do begin
      if GetTypeImagesIndex(SL.Names[I]) = -1 then
        continue;
      // FRepLines is a collection of items containing more information about each row.
      if FRepLines.Value(Item.Index, 'State') <> '1' then begin // no error
        TypeName := SL.Names[I];
        TypeState := StrToIntDef(SL.Values[TypeName], 0);
        // State*Images are TImageList.
        if TypeState = 0 then
          StateWaitingImages.Draw(Sender.Canvas, r.Left + 17*I, r.Top, 
            GetTypeImagesIndex(TypeName))
        else
          StateDoneImages.Draw(Sender.Canvas, r.Left + 17*I, r.Top, 
            GetTypeImagesIndex(TypeName));
        CreateIconToolTip(StrToIntDef(FRepLines.Value(Item.Index, 'RepJob'), -1), 
          TypeName, r.Left + 17*I, ListView1.ViewOrigin.Y + r.Top, 
          Format(TranslateString('RepQTypeState'),
          [TranslateString(Format('RepQTypeStateN%s', [TypeName])),
           TranslateString(Format('RepQTypeState-%d', [TypeState]))]));
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Some explanation of the code:

The list is a list of reports (a report queue).  I am introducing a concept of 'AutoReports' (or scheduled reports in the UI), which I want to highlight with a light blue background (`clSkyBlue`).

In addition to that background, it also draws some icons on the Status-column, which indicates what stages the report are in and moreover, what formats a report has been ordered in (formats like PDF, Excel and HTML), and whether it has been printed and/or emailed.  An icon only appears if such an event has been *ordered*, so the number of icons are variable.

The waiting state images are greyed out versions of the done state images.  I have also tried to create some code, so when I hover over the specific icons, it has a tooltip message.

Because the code is rather dull in speed, I suspect I am doing something incredibly wrong.

Comment: It's extremely difficult to tell you what might be wrong, as you've indicated you're using `AdvancedCustomDrawItem` but provided zero code. How can we tell you what you might be doing wrong if you don't show us what you're currently doing?

Comment: The problem is in your code. Which only you can see. Please provide SSCCE, or it never happened!

Comment: I apologise; I have added my event code on `AdvancedCustomDrawItem`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HotTracking is likely enabled. That causes items to redraw as they are moused over, so the item under the mouse can be rendered differently. You are probably ignoring the hottrack state when drawing. That could account for the blackness.

You should profile your code to find the real bottleneck. Drawing code needs to be fast. I do a lot of custom drawing in a ListView and it does not behave slowly like you describe.

**Update**: Consider re-writing your code to draw individual columns in the `OnAdvancedCustomDrawSubItem` event instead of doing everything in the `OnAdvancedCustomDrawItem` event. Also, you don't need to calculate each column's bounds manually, you can use `ListView_GetSubItemRect()` instead. And lastly, you are leaking your `TStringList`.

Comment: Also, I can confirm now that HotTracking is not enabled.

Comment: When I move the subitem code to the `OnAdvancedCustomDrawSubItem` event, the icons are no longer drawn.  The `Rect.Left` gotten from `ListView_GetSubItemRect()` seems to be correct, but the icons are not drawn.  Is it because they are both drawing on the `cdPostPaint` stage?

Comment: Instead of owner-drawing the icons, have you looked at using the `TListItem.SubItemImages[]` property yet?

Comment: But doesn't SubItemImages only draw *one* image per subitem?  Or is it possible to have it draw a row of images in one subitem?  Because I want the images to appear under the same column.